# OpenERP Product status by default confirmed

Tags: product, openerp-7, purchase-order

I have customized the OpenERP Products module and introduced the workflow statuses called **Draft, Pending, Confirmed** and **Cancelled**.
However, not sure what is the mistake I did while doing this.

1. When *Admin* creating a product by default it's status is setting to
   **Confirmed** status.  (**WRONG**)
2. But when normal user creates a product it is setting to **Draft** status.  (**CORRECT**)

I want same to be happen when Admin create also.

This is happening in Purchase Orders module also.

Am I doing any thing wrong?

**EDIT:**  (code)

```
from osv import fields, osv
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_inherit =  'product.product'

_columns = {
    'stage': fields.selection([
                    ('draft', 'Draft Product'),
                    ('pending', 'Pending'),
                    ('validated', 'Validated'),
                    ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
                    ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ], 'Status', select=True, track_visibility='onchange', help='Product Workflow Stages')
}

_defaults = {
    'type' : 'consu',
    'stage': 'draft',
}

purchase_order()



class product_supplierinfo(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'product.supplierinfo'
_columns = {
    'default_sup': fields.boolean('Default Supplier', help="By checking the Default Supplier field you can set a supplier as a default for this product."),
}

_defaults = {
         'default_sup': 0
    }


product_supplierinfo()
```

Comment: @Mansi,  I have updated my code here.  Rest of the flow implementation I did through customization only.

Comment: by reviewing this code, this will not create problem which you are facing now. so is there any other code you have done? or you have customized wrongly. Do share more details what you have done so that I can help you

Comment: Thank you.  I have just implemented the workflow through customization. This means nothing but creating signals for "Validate" and "Confirm" buttons and workflow nodes like source node and destination node.  Really I am not sure how can I explain you better, since I did not do any coding other than customization through UI.